# generate a range between two alphanumeric values in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a set of data where each item has a 'range from' and 'range to' string of varying types. For example the first item might have 1A0 -> 1A9 and the next item might be 3C2 -> 5F8 and so on (with several different patterns but usually consisting of a static section and a range section (it seems that usually any letter is static and numbers can either be static or not).

Is there any ready built function in pyspark that can cope with generating the intermediate values in the range? Or if not any tips on how to build one?

here my case :

```
from pyspark.sql.types import * \
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]") \
                    .appName('SparkTest.com') \
                    .getOrCreate()

data = [
    ('A', ['100', '105']),
    ('B', ['200']),
    ('C', ['1A0','1A3']), 
    ('D', ['1BB', ]), 
    ('E', ['3C8',  '3D2'])
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["id", "label"], ArrayType(StringType()))
df.show()

+---+----------+
|id |label     |
+---+----------+
|A  |[100, 105]|
|B  |[200]     |
|C  |[1A0, 1A3]|
|D  |[1BB]     |
|E  |[3C8, 3D2]|
+---+----------+
```

expected :

```
+---+-----+
|id |label|
+---+-----+
|A  |100  |
|A  |101  |
|A  |102  |
|A  |103  |
|A  |104  |
|A  |105  |
|B  |200  |
|C  |1A0  |
|C  |1A1  |
|C  |1A2  |
|C  |1A3  |
|D  |1BB  |
|E  |3C8  |
|E  |3C9  |
|E  |3D0  |
|E  |3D1  |
|E  |3D2  |
+---+-----+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a UDF which returns a array of the full range of values, then use `explode()` on that array. Here's my attempt to implement the UDF.

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode, udf

@udf(returnType=ArrayType(StringType()))
def generate_range(endpoints):
    if len(endpoints) == 1:
        return endpoints
    current, end = endpoints
    results = [current]
    # get values of each position and the modulo for the increment math
    base = ["0" if "0" <= c <= "9" else "A" for c in current]
    values = [ord(c) - ord(b) for c, b in zip(current, base)]
    modulo = [10 if b == "0" else 26 for b in base]
    while current < end:
        # increment logic
        idx = -1
        values[idx] += 1
        while values[idx] == modulo[idx]:
            values[idx] = 0
            idx -= 1
            values[idx] += 1
        current = "".join(chr(v + ord(b)) for v, b in zip(values, base))
        results.append(current)
    return results

df.select("id", explode(generate_range("label")).alias("label")).show()

+---+-----+
| id|label|
+---+-----+
|  A|  100|
|  A|  101|
|  A|  102|
|  A|  103|
|  A|  104|
|  A|  105|
|  B|  200|
|  C|  1A0|
|  C|  1A1|
|  C|  1A2|
|  C|  1A3|
|  D|  1BB|
|  E|  3C8|
|  E|  3C9|
|  E|  3D0|
|  E|  3D1|
|  E|  3D2|
+---+-----+
```

Note: This assumes the length of the items in the range won't increase during the range and will fail if it does. Let me know if this assumption is wrong.